# Cleanest workaround for incrementing function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm trying to create a function increments its parameters every time it is run. You could always rewrite the functions manually, but I'm going to be running this function several times and would like to be able to conveniently reuse the code.

```js
$("div").each(function() {

    function rangeF(firstValue, increment) {

      var first = firstValue + "-"; //Set the first value and put a hypen after it
      firstValue += increment; //Increment it by the increment
      var second = firstValue; //Set the second value
      firstValue++; //Increment by one to avoid duplicates

      return first + second; //return both values (e.g. 1-2 or x-y)
    }

    range = rangeF(5 , 10); //5 is the value to start on, 10 + 1 is the increment (need to access both 5 + 10 & 5 + 11)
    range2 = rangeF(2, 2); //2 is the value to start on, 2 + 1 is the increment (need to access both 2 + 2 & 2 + 3)

    $(this)
    .append('<div>' + range + '</div>')
    .append('<div>' + range2 + '</div>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

#1 range: <div></div>
<br />
#2 range: <div></div>
<br />
#3 range: <div></div>
```

Right now, it is showing:

```
#1 range:
P 5-15
P 2-4

#2 range:
P 5-15
P 2-4

#3 range:
P 5-15
P 2-4
```

I would like to display:

```
#1 range:
P 5-15
P 2-4

#2 range:
P 16-26
P 5-7

#3 range:
P 27-37
P 8-10
```

in the cleanest, reusable way possible.

Thanks in advance.

**Update** Sorry for the confusion, but I meant that I would like to not use repeated use global variables for solution... Thanks again for all your contributions.

Comment: What exactly are you doing with your current function? Could your explain or comment it?

Comment: Would it be ok for you to put a variable after $("div").each(function() { ?

Comment: @Daidon he did say "I would like to save global variables for the last resort."

Comment: @Daidon Sure! As long as I wouldn't have to keep adding variables.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts If Daidon provides a clean solution, I could always localized it :)

Comment: @ChrisHappy Okay, answer commin' up

Comment: you are not using any global variables

Comment: @r3wt Could you expand on that?

Comment: @ChrisHappy No, but let me rephrase *Your code example shows no reason to need to use global variables*. why you chose to omit the `var` keyword in front of the assignment of `range` and `range2` is beyond me. it serves no purpose and your code will work without it. Admittedly, i have no idea what the hell you are doing, but, you should check the documentation for `$().each()` anyway. it already provides an incremented value for each iteration of the loop anyway, and its easy to select the previous iteration of the loops value and get its range without using variables at all.

Comment: @r3wt Thanks for your feedback. The above code is a minified version of my actual code. I could remove the variables in the mini version, but it was necessary here as I had to use it out of this function. I could use the index provided, but it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks again for your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend solving this with a factory:

```js
// jQuery plugin named rangify
$.fn.rangify = function rangify(ranges) {
  // factory to generate auto-incrementers
  function rangeFactory(value, increment) {
    // scoped variables `value` and `increment`
    // re-used by inner function
    
    // this is essentially the same
    // function as in original question
    return function range() {
      var first = value;

      value += increment;

      var second = value;

      value++;

      return 'P ' + first + '-' + second;
    }
  }

  // when jQuery plugin is called
  // this initializes scoped auto-incrementers
  // with arguments supplied from array of tuples
  var calls = ranges.map(function map(args) {
    return rangeFactory(args[0], args[1]);
  });
  
  // iterate through context of jQuery selector
  return this.each(function each() {
    // reference to single element in jQuery selector
    var $this = $(this);

    // for each auto-incrementer
    calls.forEach(function (call) {
      // append the generated range
      $this.append('<div>' + call() + '</div>');
    });
  });
};

// tell plugin to generate
// 1. sequential ranges of 10 starting at 5
// 2. sequential ranges of 2 starting at 2
$("div").rangify([[5, 10], [2, 2]]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

#1 range: <div></div>
<br />
#2 range: <div></div>
<br />
#3 range: <div></div>
```

I wrote a jQuery plugin for you that uses the factory to store scoped variables in place of global variables like you were trying to avoid.

### Update

I've just created an even more generic plugin where you can specify the content returned by given arguments, and how to increment the arguments each time:

```js
// jQuery plugin named rangify
$.fn.rangify = function rangify(getter, increment, tuples) {
  // decorator to transform getter into auto-incrementing getter
  function decorator(tuple) {
    // scoped variable `tuple`
    // re-used by decorated function
    return function decorated() {
      // get content from getter
      var content = getter.apply(undefined, tuple);

      // increment the arguments for the getter
      tuple = increment.apply(undefined, tuple);
      
      // return the content
      return content;
    }
  }

  // when jQuery plugin is called
  // this initializes scoped auto-incrementers
  // with arguments supplied from array of tuples
  var calls = tuples.map(decorator);
  
  // iterate through context of jQuery selector
  return this.each(function each() {
    // reference to single element in jQuery selector
    var $this = $(this);

    // for each auto-incrementer
    calls.forEach(function (call) {
      // append the generated content
      $this.append(call());
    });
  });
};

// you supply the following functions to the plugin

// return content
function content(value, increment) {
  var first = value;
  var second = value + increment;

  return '<div>P ' + first + '-' + second + '</div>';
}

// return incremented arguments
function increment(value, increment) {
  value += increment + 1;
  
  return arguments;
}

// tell plugin to generate content
$("div").rangify(content, increment, [[5, 10], [2, 2]]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

#1 range: <div></div>
<br />
#2 range: <div></div>
<br />
#3 range: <div></div>
```

To demonstrate why this is generic, consider the following example:

```js
// jQuery plugin named rangify
$.fn.rangify = function rangify(getter, increment, tuples) {
  // decorator to transform getter into auto-incrementing getter
  function decorator(tuple) {
    // scoped variable `tuple`
    // re-used by decorated function
    return function decorated() {
      // get content from getter
      var content = getter.apply(undefined, tuple);

      // increment the arguments for the getter
      tuple = increment.apply(undefined, tuple);
      
      // return the content
      return content;
    }
  }

  // when jQuery plugin is called
  // this initializes scoped auto-incrementers
  // with arguments supplied from array of tuples
  var calls = tuples.map(decorator);
  
  // iterate through context of jQuery selector
  return this.each(function each() {
    // reference to single element in jQuery selector
    var $this = $(this);

    // for each auto-incrementer
    calls.forEach(function (call) {
      // append the generated content
      $this.append(call());
    });
  });
};

// you supply the following functions to the plugin

// return content
function content(className, chapter, section) {
  return '<div class="' + className + '">Chapter ' + chapter + ' - Section ' + section + '</div>';
}

// return incremented arguments
function increment(className, chapter, section) {
  if (section === 'C') {
    section = 'A';
    chapter++;
  } else {
    var nextCode = section.charCodeAt(0) + 1;
    section = String.fromCharCode(nextCode);
  }
  
  return arguments;
}

// tell plugin to generate content
$("div").rangify(content, increment, [['red', 1, 'A'], ['green', 4, 'A']]);
```

```css
div:not([class]) {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @ChrisHappy I added an even more generic solution. You can choose which one you'd like to use

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are after as the question is ambiguous, however this will inject to arguments into the decorated function that will increment each call of the decorated function.

The counter is held with in the closure of the `incrementRangeDecorator` function so it's not exposed to the global scope.

```js
// function decorator that will inject two argements into the 
// decorated function that will be incremented each call
const incrementRangeDecorator = function(start, increment, fn) {
  return function(...args) {
    const ret = fn(start, start += increment, ...args)
    start = start + 1
    return ret
  }
}

// function to decorate
function rangeF(start, current, extraArg) {
  console.log('called rangeF()', `${start}-${current}`, extraArg)
}

// decorate rangeF with the incrementRangeDecorator
const incrementBy2 = incrementRangeDecorator(2, 2, rangeF)
const incrementBy5 = incrementRangeDecorator(5, 10, rangeF)


incrementBy2('you')
incrementBy2('can')
incrementBy2('pass')

incrementBy5('extra')
incrementBy5('arguments')
incrementBy5()
```

Comment: Looks promising, but `const incrementBy2 = incrementRangeDecorator(2, rangeF)` doesn't add 1 to it afterward...

Comment: @ChrisHappy I think that is what you mean.

Comment: @ChrisHappy also you should note that the increment for (5, 10) is actually eleven. It will probably be confusing for anyone else looking at the code

Comment: Right, and you just need to access the number of 1 minus from it... Updating question.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
$(function() {

});
```

will wait with the execution, till DOM is ready. (This is equivalent to .ready() function and is even recommended to be used instead of .ready()...)

The variables inside that won't be 'global', they will belong to that function.

The rest explains itself.

```js
$(function() {
    var a = 5; var b = 10; var c = 2; var d = 2;
    $("div").each(function() { 
        function rangeF(firstValue, increment) {   
            var first = firstValue + "-"; //Set the first value and put a hypen after it
            firstValue += increment; //Increment it by the increment
            var second = firstValue; //Set the second value
            firstValue++; //Increment by one to avoid duplicates
            return first + second; //return both values (e.g. 1-2 or x-y)
        }
  
        range = rangeF(a, b);
        range2 = rangeF(c, d);
  
        a = a+b+1;
        c = c+d+1;
  
        $(this)
        .append('<div>' + range + '</div>')
        .append('<div>' + range2 + '</div>');
    });
});
```

```css
div {
    border:#999 1px solid;
    padding:1em;
    margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="A">
</div>
<div id="B">
</div>
<div id="C">
</div>
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Can you explain a little more clearly what you are trying to do? This function will be executed once when the page is loaded, right? Maybe I can adjust the code if I know what you are trying to achieve. :-)

Comment: Okay, but isn't my solution doing exactly what you want? The variables don't get globally saved. They are only saved while calculating to the end.

Comment: What is the end goal? You want to have a function rangeF, that will calculate the increments for a certain element? And you want to be able to call that function for other elements too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129759/discussion-between-daidon-and-chris-happy).